# Json in python loop

Tags: python, json, telegram, telepot

I'm a total beginner, I have a question: I'm going to create a telegram bot using botogram, I would like to insert my list's element in a JSON code by python loop. In this case I would like to create buttons with New York, LA, and Washington, `{'text': i}`, but on telegram appears just one button with the last item (Washington). I want to create 3 buttons.

```
import botogram
import json

bot = botogram.create("token")

list = ['New York',"LA", "Washington DC"]

@bot.command("start")
def start_command(chat, message):
    for i in list:
        bot.api.call('sendMessage', {
            'chat_id': chat.id,
            'text': 'Where are you?',
            'reply_markup': json.dumps({
            'keyboard': [
                [
                    {'text': i},
                    {'text': 'Action B'},
                ],
                [
                    {
                        'text': 'Use geolocation',
                        'request_location': True,
                    },
                ],
            ],
            'resize_keyboard': True,
            'one_time_keyboard': True,
            'selective': True,
        }),
    })

if __name__ == "__main__":
     bot.run()
```

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name, it overwrites the `list()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't looping over `list` to create three buttons, you're looping over `list` to send three messages.  Create your button definition list and then add to it within your loop, then send the message outside of the loop.

Comment: Sorry, but i've this error: Response from Telegram: "Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"

Comment: @AbdulGandal then you have a new problem, so open a new question and put your new version of your code into it along with the new error message.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used botogram, but as I see it, I suggest you create a variable in the **for** loop (a dictionary - dict) and then call **bot.api.call**

```
@bot.command("start")
def start_command(chat, message):
    for i in list:
        dict = {
            'chat_id': chat.id,
            'text': 'Where are you?',
            'reply_markup': {
            'keyboard': [[
                {'text': i},
                {'text': 'Action B'},
            ],
            [
                {
                    'text': 'Use geolocation',
                    'request_location': True,
                },
            ],
        ],
        'resize_keyboard': True,
        'one_time_keyboard': True,
        'selective': True, 
        }
    }
    bot.api.call('sendMessage', dict)
```

I hope that helps you, at least a little bit!

Comment: How have i to use  bot.api.call('sendMessage', dict)

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Sorry, but i've this error: Response from Telegram: "Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"

Comment: Sorry, but i've this error: Response from Telegram: "Bad Request: can't parse reply keyboard markup JSON object"

Comment: Oh, you can use json.loads(dict). Maybe that helps!